# Is there a way to use RDKit without Anaconda or Conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, rdkit

RDKit is a Python library for chemistry. I don't want to use an Anaconda distribution, and I am not sure (from the documentation: https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html ) if there is a way to use the package without it. Can someone give me some pointers on installing and using this without conda or installing an Anaconda distribution?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation does provide directions for [installing from alternative repositories](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html#installation-from-repositories) (e.g, `homebrew`) or [building from source](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html#building-from-source).

Nevertheless, Conda is the simplest path, and just because you don't want *Anaconda* (neither do I!), that shouldn't deter you from enjoying the benefits of deep dependency management that *Conda* provides. There are minimal and performant distributions, like [Mambaforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge), that users only focused on environment and package management often find preferable. Also, don’t use the **base** environment for work, but create a new one, like

```
mamba create -n rdkit rdkit
```

Comment: That is so helpful, thank you so much! I still need to figure out what "building from source" means (in case you have a good tutorial on hand, I would appreciate it!)

Answer (score 0):

I just installed `rdkit` and then installed `jupyter` (without anaconda), and it is working. It works in PyCharm too, but I'm not able to display images of molecules as SVG files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not a fan of conda as it is a half-step to installing software in docker images, which is a better solution.  And the shell heroics, while clever, are clunky.  And installs are crazy slow.

You should be able to do a direct install w/ pip:

```
python3 -m pip install rdkit
```

This will install it into wherever the current python3 interpreter has its default modules, without `conda`.  You may need to run with `sudo`.  You can install it into a virtualenv with:

```
python3 -m venv env
. env/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install rdkit
```

Note that the examples above work with any recent version of python3, and circumvent the `pip` CLI which often leaves it ambiguous which python3 version the install is applied-to.